# Can you identify set from these parts?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

[image]

I bought this set too long time ago. But now I can not remember set number so can not assemble. Please help me

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be that these elements belong to more than one set.

Polybags with [green window shutters](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=60800&colorID=6&in=A) are from [Doors and Windows (6117)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6117-1)

[image]

Polybags containing [blue flag](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2335&colorID=7&in=A) and some other elements in Bright Light Orange are from [The Lion CHI Temple (70010)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70010-1)

[image]

Comment: U r genious!!! Tq!!!!

Comment: The box art for 6117 is so strange and mesmerizing.  I'm glad they're trying to make clear that you don't get the building too, but the result is an odd-looking LEGO box.